# Why can't I pass index field value into painless script?

Tags: elasticsearch-painless

Here's my index:

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "virtual": "/testss/3-1.pdf",
  "file": "3-1",
  "caseno": "testss"
}
```

I am trying to pass the file value "3-1" into the following script and then conditionally either return the value or divide it by 100:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "mynewfield": {
      "script": { 
        "source":"""
     List i=Arrays.asList(doc['file'].value.splitOnToken("-"));
     if (i.length==1){
       return Float.parseFloat(i[0]);
    }
  if (i.length==2){
       return Float.parseFloat(i[0])+Float.parseFloat(i[1])/100;
    }   
     """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And Getting following errors:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:757)",
          "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116)",
          "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.lambda$lookup$0(QueryShardContext.java:330)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:97)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
          "java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)",
          "i=Arrays.asList(doc['file'].value.splitOnToken(\"-\"));\n     ",
          "                    ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "\n       \n     List i=Arrays.asList(doc['file'].value.splitOnToken(\"-\"));\n     if (i.length==1){\n       return Float.parseFloat(i[0]);\n    }\n  if (i.length==2){\n       return Float.parseFloat(i[0])+Float.parseFloat(i[1])/100;\n    }\n   \n      \n      ",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 39,
          "start" : 19,
          "end" : 78
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "my-index-000001",
        "node" : "wJdb2G1VQCyaDNduQLS4SQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:757)",
            "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116)",
            "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.lambda$lookup$0(QueryShardContext.java:330)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:97)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
            "java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)",
            "i=Arrays.asList(doc['file'].value.splitOnToken(\"-\"));\n     ",
            "                    ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "\n       \n     List i=Arrays.asList(doc['file'].value.splitOnToken(\"-\"));\n     if (i.length==1){\n       return Float.parseFloat(i[0]);\n    }\n  if (i.length==2){\n       return Float.parseFloat(i[0])+Float.parseFloat(i[1])/100;\n    }\n   \n      \n      ",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 39,
            "start" : 19,
            "end" : 78
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [file] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

What should I do differently here?

I tried referencing File: "3-1" with doc['file'].value in the script...doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

> POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query/ {   "script": {
> "lang": "painless",
> "source": "ctx._source.caseno=Arrays.asList(ctx._source.virtual.splitOnToken('/'))[1];ctx._source.file=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(ctx._source.virtual.splitOnToken('/'))[2].splitOnToken('.'))[0];List
> i=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(ctx._source.virtual.splitOnToken('/'))[2].splitOnToken('.'))[0].splitOnToken('-'));if
> (i.length==1){ctx._source.mynewfield=Float.parseFloat(i[0]);}if
> (i.length==2){ctx._source.mynewfield=Float.parseFloat(i[0])+Float.parseFloat(i[1])/100}"
> } }